# Using the definition of limit prove the following

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

Using the definition of limit prove that

$$\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{2x^2+x+1}{x^2-3x+1}=2$$
$$\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{x-[x]}{x}=0$$ $[x]$ greatest integer function

Please help me to solve such type of problem using $\epsilon$-$K$ method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need the following:

**Definition** We say that $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=L$, where $L\in\Bbb R$, if for every $\epsilon>0$, we can find $K>0$ such that for all $x>K$, we have $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$.

We have to prove that
$$\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{2x^2+x+1}{x^2-3x+1}=2.$$

**Proof:** Let $\epsilon>0$. Choose $K\in\Bbb N$ such that $K>\frac{9}{2}$ and $\frac{1}{K}<\frac{\epsilon}{21}$. (Hope you get this.). Observe that
$$\begin{align}
x>\frac{9}{2}&\implies 2x>9\\
&\implies 3x-9>x\\
&\implies x-3>\frac{x}{3}\\
&\implies \frac{x-3}{7}>\frac{x}{21}\\
&\implies \frac{7}{x-3}<\frac{21}{x}.
\end{align}$$
Therefore, if $x>K>\frac{9}{2}$ then we get 
$$\begin{align}
\bigg|\frac{2x^2+x+1}{x^2-3x+1}-2\bigg|&=\bigg|\frac{7x-1}{x^2-3x+1}\bigg|\\
&=\frac{7x-1}{x^2-3x+1}\\
&<\frac{7x}{x^2-3x+1}\\
&<\frac{7x}{x^2-3x}\\
&=\frac{7x}{x(x-3)}\\
&=\frac{7}{x-3}<\frac{21}{x}<\frac{21}{K}<\epsilon.
\end{align}$$
Apply the definition and we are done.

Answer (score 2):

For part $1$, we have:

$$2x^2+x+1=2(x^2-3x+1)+7x-1$$

For part $2$, use:

$$0\le x-\lfloor x\rfloor=\{x\}\lt1$$

To use $\epsilon-\delta$, we then need to prove that given $\epsilon\gt0$, we can always find a $\delta$ such that, if $\frac1x\lt\frac1\delta$ (or equivalently $x\gt\delta$), the given $f(x)$ is $\lt\epsilon$.

In the first case, $f(x)=\big|\dfrac{7x-1}{x^2-3x+1}\big|$. Let $\delta=\frac1\epsilon$.

$f(\delta)=\big|\dfrac{1/\epsilon-1}{1/\epsilon^2-3/\epsilon+1}\big|=\big|\dfrac{\epsilon-\epsilon^2}{1-3\epsilon+\epsilon^2}\big|=\epsilon\big|\dfrac{1-\epsilon}{1-3\epsilon+\epsilon^2}\big|\to\epsilon\to0$ as $\epsilon\to0$.

In the second case, we can use $f(x)=|\frac1x|$ and the Squeeze Theorem, and $\delta=\frac1\epsilon$.

$f(\delta)=|\epsilon|=\epsilon$.

Comment: $|\frac{2x^2+x+1}{x^2-3x+1}-2|=|\frac{7x-1}{x^2-3x+1}|$. How to prove that it is $< \epsilon$ when $|x-2|<\delta$

Comment: $|\frac{x-[x]}{x}-0|=|\frac{\{x\}}{x}|<\frac{1}{x}$ as $\{x\}\lt1$. But **how to show** $|\frac{x-[x]}{x}-0|<\epsilon$ whenever $|x-0|<\delta$

Comment: $x\to\infty$ so this doesn't happen very often, unless $\delta$ is large.

Comment: then how to handle with it

Comment: Also what about the 2nd

Comment: @user1942348; i've updated my answer, does it make sense to you?

Comment: Not convinced with the 1st solution. I want to use $0 < |x - a| < \delta \quad \Rightarrow \quad |f(x) - l| < \epsilon$

Comment: @ΘΣΦGenSan Would you please comment here for this question.

Comment: @user1942348 Ah okay, wait for  a moment.  I will do the first only since part 2 was solved already in detailed by JonMark Perry.

Comment: @user1942348 It took me too long to find the proof. Anyway, just look into it and feel free to ask.

Comment: @ΘΣΦGenSan Q1. Why you take 9/2,    Q2. Why you take $\epsilon/21$, Q3.  Have you considered the positiveness of the denominator in writing $|\frac{7x-1}{x^2-3x+1}|=\frac{7x-1}{x^2-3x+1}$

Comment: user1942348 That's part of the whole trick. The choice of $\frac{9}{2}$ is to ensure that if I have $x>\frac{9}{2}$ then I will get $x^2-3x+1>0$. Then the choice of $\frac{\epsilon}{21}$ follows. The approach is actually not unique. Its just happened that I made those choices.