# Use the definition of limit to prove that $\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{x+\lfloor x\rfloor }{x^2}=0$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

Use the definition of limit to prove that $\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{x+\lfloor x\rfloor}{x^2}=0$.

Attempt:

to show

$0 < |x - a| < \delta \quad \Rightarrow \quad |f(x) - 0| < \epsilon$, but here  $a=\infty$.

Please help me to solve the problem.

Comment: You need to show that for every $\epsilon$ there exists a $K \geq 0$ such that, if $|x| > K$, $|f(x)| < \epsilon$. This is the definition for "$a = \infty$".

Comment: You should look at the definition of $$\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=L$$ where $L\in\Bbb R$. This is called limit at infinity.

Comment: BTW, what do you mean by $[x]$? Does it refers to the greatest integer function?

Comment: yes, greatest integer function

Comment: If $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)$ be exist then $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}f(n)$.

Comment: @ΘΣΦGenSan  Please solve the problem for me

Comment: The title of your post is not appropriate since the definition does not involved $\epsilon$-$\delta$, rather in involves $\epsilon$-$K$.

Comment: Since $x \to \infty$, the definition should be $\forall \varepsilon>0 \exists M > 0 \forall |x| > M, |f(x)-L| < \varepsilon$

Comment: @GNU Supporter Do we really require $|x|>M$ or should it be $x>M$?

Comment: @GNU Supporter Maybe you are thinking $x\to\infty$ to mean either $x\to +\infty$ or $x\to -\infty$ that is why you put $|x|>M$?

Comment: @ΘΣΦGenSan It's clear that in this question it doesn't matter, nor this questions involving sequences.  Yes, you're right.  You may view $X = \Bbb R$ and $d_X(x,0) = |x|$ in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/(ε,_δ)-definition_of_limit#Precise_statement_for_limits_at_infinity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you need the following definition

**Definition** We say that $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=L$, where $L\in\Bbb R$, if for every $\epsilon>0$, we can find $K>0$ such that for all $x>K$, we have $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$.

We have to prove that $$\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{x+[x]}{x^2}=0,$$
where $[x]$ is called the greatest integer function.

---

**Proof:** First, we need to observe that $\forall x\in\Bbb R$, 
$$x-1<\color\red{[x]\leq x}.$$  So, adding both sides of the inequality $[x]\leq x$ by $x$, we get $$x+[x]\leq 2x.$$
 Let $\epsilon>0$. By using the Archimedean Property, we can choose $K\in\Bbb N$ such that $\frac{1}{K}<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$. Thus, if $x>K>0$ then
$$\begin{align}
\bigg|\frac{x+[x]}{x^2}-0\bigg|&=\bigg|\frac{x+[x]}{x^2}\bigg|\\
&=\frac{|x+[x]|}{|x^2|}\\
&=\frac{x+[x]}{x^2}\\
&\leq \frac{2x}{x^2}=\frac{2}{x}<\frac{2}{K}<\epsilon.
\end{align}$$
Apply the definition and we are done.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. Please help for the 1st question in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2182995/using-the-definition-of-limit-prove-the-following/2182998?noredirect=1#comment4490641_2182998

Comment: @user1942348 Its already done. Please check the proof.

Answer (score 1):

I've always been uncomfortable with the epsilonic proofs as they are long and seemingly "tricky" and "avoidable" as I always can use the very intuitive, and less rigorous, idea behind the symbol $\lim$. But it's a prejudice. In fact, the epsilonics use the very same "tricks" that the "usual" procedures. I've enjoyed the try. I think it's correct, but maybe (I am never sure) some points need a more detailed explanation. Anyway, you can point the errors, or the flaws:(

Let be $\epsilon>0$ given, then, let's choose $K=2/\epsilon$. We have

$$\frac{K+[K]}{K^2}=\frac{2/\epsilon+[2/\epsilon]}{(2/\epsilon)^2}\le\frac{2/\epsilon+2/\epsilon}{(2/\epsilon)^2}=\frac{4/\epsilon}{4/\epsilon^2}=\epsilon$$

Consider $x>K$, then

$$\left|\frac{x+[x]}{x^2}\right|=\frac{x+[x]}{x^2}=1/x+(1/x)([x]/x)$$

$$=(1/x)(1+[x]/x)<(1/K)(1+[K]/K)=\frac{K+[K]}{K^2}\le\epsilon\tag 1$$

So, $0$ is the limit.

$(1)$ $x>K>0\implies(1/x<1/K);\;[x]/x\le[K]/K;\;(1+[x]/x)<(1+[K]/K)$ and the inequality follows.